# How to use a type from a child package / generic package instantiation

Tags: generics, ada

I can make the primitive subprograms of a type directly visible with
`use all type` like this:

```
package Type_Package is
   type T is null record;
   procedure Action(X: T) is null;
end Type_Package;

with Type_Package;
procedure Use_Type is
   use all type Type_Package.T;
   X: Type_Package.T;
begin
   Action(X);
end Use_Type;
```

However, it does not seem to work when I move `Type_Package` inside
`Use_Type`.

```
procedure Use_Type is
   package Type_Package is
      type T is null record;
      procedure Action(X: T) is null;
   end Type_Package;
   use all type Type_Package.T;
   X: Type_Package.T;
begin
   Action(X);
end Use_Type;
```

I get

```
gcc -c use_type.adb
use_type.adb:9:04: "Action" is not visible
use_type.adb:9:04: non-visible declaration at line 4
gnatmake: "use_type.adb" compilation error
```

The same thing occurs when I instantiate a generic package.  For
example, when I want to use the data types in `Ada.Containers`.

```
package Element_Set is
   new Ada.Containers.Hashed_Sets(Element_Type, Hash, "=");
use all type Element_Set.Set;
```

The `use type` clause here seems to have no effect.

How to use a type when the type is declared in a child package or an
instantiation of a generic package?

Comment: I wonder whether the problem in your second example is that `Type_Package` isn’t at library level? (by the way, it isn’t a child package; `Containers` is a child package in `Ada.Containers`). On the other hand, [ARM 3.2.3(6)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-3-2-3.html#p6) doesn’t say that the package has to be at library level - ? It’d be easier to just say `use Type_Package;`

Comment: @SimonWright Yes, `Type_Package` is not at the library level in the second example.
And I want to know why `use type` only seems to work when it is.  And it
is harder to instantiate a generic package at the library level.  When I
said child package, I meant that `Type_Package` is declared in the
declarative part of `Use_Type`.  What is the correct term?  Using the
entire package works, but I am curious about how to use only a type.

Comment: @SimonWright It almost looks like in the latter case, the compiler isn't counting Action as a primitive operation of type T.  If I take the example and add an "=" operation, it sees that just fine with "use all type".  I couldn't find anything in the RM that clears this up.  I feel like this should be legal to do, but just a feeling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have indeed found a compiler bug.

There are a set of tests (the [Ada Conformity Assessment Test Suite](http://www.ada-auth.org/acats.html), ACATS - also [here](https://github.com/simonjwright/ACATS)) in which the "B series" are designed to check that compilers catch errors.

One of those tests, [B840003](https://github.com/simonjwright/ACATS/blob/master/tests/b8/b840003.a), starts off like your problem: a cut-down and slightly modified version behaves like this:

```
 1. procedure B840003 is
 2. begin
 3.
 4.    declare
 5.       package Pkg_1 is
 6.          type Enum is (Aaa, Bbb, Ccc);
 7.          procedure Prim_Proc (X : Enum := Aaa) is null;
 8.          function Prim_Func return Enum is (Bbb);
 9.
10.          package Nested is
11.             procedure Nonprim_Proc (X : Enum := Bbb) is null;
12.             function Nonprim_Func return Enum is (Ccc);
13.          end Nested;
14.
15.       end Pkg_1;
16.
17.    begin
18.       declare
19.          use all type Pkg_1.Enum;
20.       begin
21.          if Prim_Func /= Bbb then                                  -- OK.
22.             null;
23.          end if;
24.          if Nonprim_Func (Ccc) /= Ccc then                         -- ERROR:
                |
    >>> "Nonprim_Func" is not visible
    >>> non-visible declaration at line 12

25.             null;
26.          end if;
27.          Prim_Proc;                                                -- OK.
28.          Nonprim_Proc (Aaa);                                       -- ERROR:
             |
    >>> "Nonprim_Proc" is not visible
    >>> non-visible declaration at line 11

29.       end;
30.    end;
31.
32. end B840003;
```

(see line 27) whereas one more closely like your example (pulling the package declaration up to the declarative region of the subprogram) does this:

```
 1. procedure B840003_Mod is
 2.    package Pkg_1 is
 3.       type Enum is (Aaa, Bbb, Ccc);
 4.       procedure Prim_Proc (X : Enum := Aaa) is null;
 5.       function Prim_Func return Enum is (Bbb);
 6.
 7.       package Nested is
 8.          procedure Nonprim_Proc (X : Enum := Bbb) is null;
 9.          function Nonprim_Func return Enum is (Ccc);
10.       end Nested;
11.
12.    end Pkg_1;
13.
14.    use all type Pkg_1.Enum;
15. begin
16.    if Prim_Func /= Bbb then                                  -- OK.
17.       null;
18.    end if;
19.    if Nonprim_Func (Ccc) /= Ccc then                         -- ERROR:
          |
    >>> "Nonprim_Func" is not visible
    >>> non-visible declaration at line 9

20.       null;
21.    end if;
22.    Prim_Proc;                                                -- OK.
       |
    >>> "Prim_Proc" is not visible
    >>> non-visible declaration at line 4

23.    Nonprim_Proc (Aaa);                                       -- ERROR:
       |
    >>> "Nonprim_Proc" is not visible
    >>> non-visible declaration at line 8

24.
25. end B840003_Mod;
```

See line 22 (a procedure call; the function call at line 16 is OK!).

This is worth a bug report to AdaCore (though I wouldn’t expect them to drop everything and rush to fix it).

---

Interestingly, earlier versions of the compiler e.g. GNAT CE 2018) find `Bbb`, `Ccc` not visible.

Answer (score 2):

I"m not sure if this is a compiler bug (**Update:** Simon Wright confirmed it as a bug)  or intended, but your workaround options include:

**Use "use Type_Package" for the whole package** - Probably the easiest but most heavy handed

**Use some procedure/function rename clauses** - this takes more work but doesn't make the whole package visible. EX:

```ada
procedure Hello is
    package Type_Package is
        type T is null record;
        procedure Action(X: T) is null;
    end Type_Package;

    use all type Type_Package.T;
    X: Type_Package.T;

    procedure Action(X : Type_Package.T) renames Type_Package.Action;

begin
    Action(X);
end Hello;
```

**for generic packages, declare them at library level** - This won't help with nested packages, but will for generic.  You can do this for a single generic package doing the following:

*Type_Package.ads*

```ada
with Use_All_Type;
package Type_Package is new Use_All_Type;
```

*Use_All_Type.ads*

```ada
generic
package Use_All_Type is

   type T is null record;
   procedure Action(X: T) is null;

end Use_All_Type;
```

or for multiple generic packages:

*Type_Package.ads*

```ada
with Use_All_Type;
package Type_Package is 
   package UAT is new Use_All_Type;
   subtype T is UAT.T;
   use all type UAT.T;

   -- repeat for other generics
end Type_Package;
```

*Use_All_Type.ads*

```ada
generic
package Use_All_Type is

   type T is null record;
   procedure Action(X: T) is null;

end Use_All_Type;
```

Both of those methods will work with the following main:

```ada
with Type_Package;

procedure Main is

   use all type Type_Package.T;
   X: Type_Package.T;

begin
   Action(X);
end Main;
```

Side Note:  You might consider sending AdaCore a bug report if no one here answers definitively on whether this is intended or not.